# Xcode - iOS Build Fails

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

I get this error while trying to build with `react-native run-ios`

> Building SprungFit/SprungFit [Debug] Check Dependencies Linking
> SprungFit
>
> clang: error: unknown argument: '-no_deduplicate'
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory:
> '/Users/prameet/Sites/projects/rnmobile/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SprungFit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SprungFit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SprungFit_lto.o'
>
> Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SprungFit.app
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory: '2'
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory:
> '/Users/prameet/Sites/projects/rnmobile/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SprungFit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SprungFit.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SprungFit_dependency_info.dat'

This happens when I build on simulator. I tried deleting Derived Data and cleaning the project. But still it doesn't work.